# Keyboard input is not working in 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, input-method

Keyboard input is not working in 18.04. It always works till I unlock - type in password. After that it works only sporadically.

A stop icon is also displayed sometimes over the screen. Why does this happen? I think this could be a software problem because this never occurs while typing in password. How do I fix this? Screenshot attached.

I'm using a lenovo ideapad 320, ubuntu is the only OS in the laptop. <s>This problem seems to go away when Florence is running.</s>

Update: This affects the virtual keyboard as well. This problem only occurs in workspaces.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any GNOME extensions like **Workspaces to Dock** installed?

Comment: No, i dont have any such extensions.

Comment: Please tell us your computer brand/model. Also, was another OS preinstalled, did the keyboard work at any time? Did you try another keyboard?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: After update my ubuntu 18.04. My input now only works for the main monitor, it is mess in another monitor.